# How do you use std::make_shared to create a smart pointer of a base class type?

Tags: c++

What am I doing wrong here? I cannot believe the below doesn't compile. Do you need to use a shared pointer cast or something?

```
struct Base
{
};

class Child : Base
{
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> p = std::make_shared<Child>();
}
```

The error I get with Microsoft compiler is

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr<Child>' to 'std::shared_ptr<Base>'
```

Comment: I think you need to publicly inherit from `Base`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does work. It's just that `Base` has `private` inheritance.

```
struct Child : Base{};
```

or

```
class Child : public Base{};
```

are fixes. Interestingly `std::static_pointer_cast` and company do exist; but you don't need them here. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Comment: Right that works, but I thought the inheritance was public?

Comment: you get the default access modifier of the type that implements a class. So if you do `class Child ...`, the default is private, if you do `struct Child ...` the default is public.

Comment: No, because the child class is a `class`, inheritance is `private` by default, just like member variables and functions.

Comment: And we do not need `std::static_pointer_cast` here because we are casting do base class (going up in the hierarchy), right? I assume the rules are the same as for "normal" `static_cast`, which we would need if we casted in the other direction, i.e. from `Base` to `Derived`.

Answer (score 6):

Although [@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba)'s and [@divinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3056501/divinas)'s answers solved this issue, none of them explained why is this the solution, and I think it's important for future viewers to know why is it the problem in this case.

When you are trying to create a pointer to the base class `Base` you are trying to get an access to all of the public members of the base that belong to the derived class (in this case `Child`). If the derived class privately inherit the base class (or protected inherit it), all of the members that labeled as public in the base class, inside the derived class now labeled as private (or protected). Which means that the attempt to access them as public members will raise an access privileges violation issue. Because the access privileges is known at the compile time, this is a compilation error.

The solve, as mentioned in previous responses, is to inherit the base class using public inheritance. Which is the default inheritance in `struct`s and non-default inheritance in `class`es.

Answer (score 5):

You should use public inheritance instead:

```
class Child : public Base
{
};
```

Comment: If I had a dollar for every `;` I've added on this site...

Comment: I'm $3 richer on this page alone, plus The Fed are good at creating money at the moment.